# Registration-free COM and multiple offers of the same interface

Tags: com, regfreecom

We have a suite of components which offer the same set of interfaces.
While investigating the possibility of client code using registration-free COM, we stumbled upon this problem.
One client may use different implementations of the same inteface, depending on configuration provided by the user. Therefore, it must include a dependency for each one of these components.
Each one of these components contains a comInterfaceProxyStub element registering the exported component interface.
That is, we have many components with a comInterfaceProxyStub exporting the same set of interfaces, which they all implement.
It seems this fact causes an error at activation time. ststrace.exe is not clear but it seems it is refusing to "register again".
What are we missing?
Is it supposed to be an error trying to activate a second component with a comInterfaceProxyStub element for an interface already "registered"?

Comment: Different interfaces should have different GUIDs.

Comment: Yes, of course. We are offering multiple implementations of the same interfaces.

Comment: I have added some more text to make it clear we have multiple components offering the same set of interfaces.

Comment: If these interfaces do not need to be marshalled then you shouldn't need any proxying anyway.  Have you tested using a manifest without these `comInterfaceProxyStub` elements defined?  Your shared interface is already compiled-in if your clients are using early binding.

Comment: The `Microsoft.Windows.ActCtx` object is an easy to use wrapper around the Activation Context API.  Each library implementing the common interface would have its own manifest file.